# Passing a tuple argument to RandomSearchCV in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

I am trying to implement a truly random grid search using `scikit-learn`, specifically for the `MLPRegressor` model.

```
model = Pipeline([
            ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
            ('mlp', MLPRegressor())
        ])
```

This model takes a tuple argument `hidden_layer_sizes`. I am unable to pass a tuple argument to the `param_distributions` argument of the `RandomizedSearchCV` function. After some tries, I found a workaround, but I don't think this is the most efficient way of doing this.

For some background, I can use a predefined grid as follows and it works fine

```
fixed_grid = [
  {'mlp__hidden_layer_sizes': [(10,10), (20,20)], 
   'mlp__tol': [1e-3, 1e-2],
   'mlp__max_iter': [5000, 10000]
  }
]
```

However, a random grid does not work as expected as it is not able to sample the tuple correctly.

```
from scipy.stats import randint
from sklearn.utils.fixes import loguniform

random_grid = [
  {'mlp__hidden_layer_sizes': [tuple([randint(10, 30), randint(10, 30)])], # 2 layers
   'mlp__tol': loguniform(1e-5, 1e-1),
   'mlp__max_iter': randint(low=500, high=2000)
  }
]
```

The above grid results in the following snippet of error

```
AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'rv_frozen' and 'int'

  FitFailedWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    737             refit_start_time = time.time()
    738             if y is not None:
--> 739                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    740             else:
    741                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, **fit_params)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    352                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
    353             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
--> 354                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    355         return self
    356 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py in fit(self, X, y)
    625         self : returns a trained MLP model.
    626         """
--> 627         return self._fit(X, y, incremental=False)
    628 
    629     @property

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py in _fit(self, X, y, incremental)
    319         # Validate input parameters.
    320         self._validate_hyperparameters()
--> 321         if np.any(np.array(hidden_layer_sizes) <= 0):
    322             raise ValueError("hidden_layer_sizes must be > 0, got %s." %
    323                              hidden_layer_sizes)

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'rv_frozen' and 'int'
```

The above error is due to the fact that the number of neurons in each layer is not sampled correctly. To debug this, I use the following code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterSampler
param_grid = {
    'a': [tuple([randint(10, 30), randint(10, 30)])],
    'b': [randint(10,30)],
    'c': [tuple(np.random.randint(10, 30, 2))],
    'd': [(random.randint(10, 30), random.randint(10, 30)) for i in range(0, 2)],
}

param_list = list(ParameterSampler(param_grid, n_iter=2, random_state=101))
param_list
```

As can be seen, the results of parameters 'a' and 'b' are not sampled correctly.

```
[{'d': (17, 14),
  'c': (23, 21),
  'b': <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen at 0x21157e15948>,
  'a': (<scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen at 0x21157dfc188>,
   <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen at 0x21157e21b88>)},
 {'d': (13, 16),
  'c': (23, 21),
  'b': <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen at 0x21157e15948>,
  'a': (<scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen at 0x21157dfc188>,
   <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen at 0x21157e21b88>)}]
```

As a workaround, I have defined the random grid as follows. Basically, I am defining a list of 100 random tuples and letting the RandomSearchCV function pick from this list. This works but there is still a chance that the number of neurons will repeat since the value used in each iteration is being sampled from a list of only 100 tuples.

```
random_grid = [
  {'mlp__hidden_layer_sizes': [(random.randint(10, 30), random.randint(10, 30)) for i in range(0, 100)], # 2 layers
   'mlp__tol': loguniform(1e-5, 1e-1),
   'mlp__max_iter': randint(low=500, high=2000)
  }
]
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient and concise way of performing this random grid search with tuple arguments?

Thanks!

Comment: Your last defined `random_grid` seems to work just fine, so not clear what exactly your issue is here

Comment: Yes, the last one works (sort of), but it is not a very concise way of defining the random search. Also, I am predefined a list of 100 tuples to choose form. So when I pass a large n_iter to the RandomSearchCV function, there is a possibility that the same tuple might get picked more than once in which case, it is not acting as a true random search. I am hoping there is a better way of passing a tuple argument to the RandomSearchCV function. I hope that clarifies the issue.

Comment: Not sure your concerns are justified; after all, in any true random search there is always the chance that some values will indeed be repeated given a large enough sample. In other words, there is not any kind of guarantee that some values will not be repeated, neither there should be such a guarantee (otherwise it is not truly random).

Comment: Yes, but that is different than me forcing some duplicates due to the process that I am using. I am just hoping there is a more concise way of doing this. This just seems like a workaround (hack) to me.

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't seem that you actually do something like that; sounds kind of a cyclical argument - you see some duplicates (which in principle are not unexpected), and you worry if they are "legitimate" (due to the inherent randomness) or spurious artifacts of your process... Tough nut (randomness can be a bitch) :)

Comment: Well, putting it another way, the probability of getting a duplicate in my process is much higher than the probability of getting a duplicate in a truly random process. One way I can reduce the probability of getting a duplicate in my process is to increase 100 to say 10,000 or 100,000 but that just seems like such a waste of memory.

Comment: Yes, in my case it is 1/100 or 1%. For the truly random process if I use 2 layers and neurons ranging from 10 to 30 (20 integers to choose from) in each layer, it is 1/400. If I increase the layers to 3, it becomes 1/8000. So yes, it is indeed higher in my process.